# JQ load windows function won't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few html documents that I link. One of them, has a `$(window).load(function())`

The function DOES work properly, because it'll execute when I refresh the page with (F5). However, when I go to that document through a link from another HTML page, the fucntion won't fire, I need to manuall refresh it.

I have nothing in the  section except the css. I load the jquery/boostrat and plugin on the index page.

Here's the map:

```
index
--products
----problem page
```

On the problem page the onload wont fire.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" /> 
        <script>
            function leslider(valor) {
                //var i = 0;
                //for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
                //      window.location.reload();
                //      }
                var elementos_lbclassic118 = document.getElementsByClassName("lbclassic118");
                var elementos_lbclassic1990 = document.getElementsByClassName("lbclassic1990");
                var total_elementos = elementos_lbclassic118.length + elementos_lbclassic1990.length;
                var i;
                for (i = 1; i < total_elementos + 1; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("age" + i).style.display = "none";
                }
                document.getElementById("age" + valor).style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
        <title>andrei</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="placeholder1"></div>
        <div id="placeholder2"></div>   
        <footer style="background-color: black; color: white; padding: 2em; margin-top: 1em;"><div id="slider"><input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="90" step="1" value="0" onchange="leslider(this.value)" /></div></footer>       <script>
            $(window).load(function () {
                $.getJSON('http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.json', function (data) {
                    var output = "<div class='outer'>";
                    for (var i in data.lbclassic118) {
                        output += "<div style='display:none;' class='lbclassic118'id=" + "age" + data.lbclassic118[i].ageinweeks + ">" + '<table class="table table-responsive"><tr class="cabecera"><th colspan="3"><center><strong>Age (weeks)' + data.lbclassic118[i].ageinweeks + '</strong></center></th></tr><tr><td rowspan="3" class="primera">Body Weight (g)</td><td class="segunda">average</td><td class="tercera" align="right"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].average + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">range min</td><td class="tercera" align="right"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].rangemin + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">range mmax</td><td class="tercera" align="right"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].rangemmax + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="3" class="primera">feed consumption</td><td class="segunda">kj bird day</td><td align="right" class="tercera"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].kjbirdday + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">g bird day</td><td align="right" class="tecera"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].gbirdday + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">cumulative</td><td align="right" class="tercera"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].cumulative + '</strong></td></tr></table>' + "</div>";
                    }
                    output += "</div>";
                    document.getElementById("placeholder1").innerHTML = output;
                });
            });
            $(window).load(function () {
                $.getJSON('http://xxxxx/xxxxxx.json', function (data) {
                    var output = "<div class='outer'>";
                    for (var i in data.lbclassic1990) {
                        output += "<div style='display:none;' class='lbclassic1990'id=" + "age" + data.lbclassic1990[i].ageinweeks + ">" + '<table class="table table-responsive"><tr class="cabecera"><th colspan="3"><center><strong>Age (weeks) ' + data.lbclassic1990[i].ageinweeks + '</strong></center></th></tr><tr><td>Egg No. per H.H.</td><td>cumul.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].cumul + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">Rate of Lay %</td><td>per H.H.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].perhh + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td>per H.D.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].perhd + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2"> Egg Weight (g)</td><td>egg weight in week</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggweightinweek + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td>egg mass cumul.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggmasscumul + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">Egg Mass -- g/H.D. -- kg/H.H.</td><td>egg mass in week</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggmassinweek + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td>egg mass cumul.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggmasscumul2 + '</strong></td></tr></table>' + "</div>";
                    }
                    output += "</div>";
                    document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML = output;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the window will not be updated. If you click on a link, only the document will be replaced / loaded.

Please try 
`$(document).ready(function() { ...`

Instead of 
`$(window).load(function () { ...`

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try updating your JavaScript to the following:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.json', function (data) {
            var output = "<div class='outer'>";
            for (var i in data.lbclassic118) {
                output += "<div style='display:none;' class='lbclassic118'id=" + "age" + data.lbclassic118[i].ageinweeks + ">" + '<table class="table table-responsive"><tr class="cabecera"><th colspan="3"><center><strong>Age (weeks)' + data.lbclassic118[i].ageinweeks + '</strong></center></th></tr><tr><td rowspan="3" class="primera">Body Weight (g)</td><td class="segunda">average</td><td class="tercera" align="right"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].average + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">range min</td><td class="tercera" align="right"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].rangemin + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">range mmax</td><td class="tercera" align="right"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].rangemmax + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="3" class="primera">feed consumption</td><td class="segunda">kj bird day</td><td align="right" class="tercera"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].kjbirdday + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">g bird day</td><td align="right" class="tecera"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].gbirdday + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td class="segunda">cumulative</td><td align="right" class="tercera"><strong>' + data.lbclassic118[i].cumulative + '</strong></td></tr></table>' + "</div>";
            }
            output += "</div>";
            document.getElementById("placeholder1").innerHTML = output;
        });
        $.getJSON('http://xxxxx/xxxxxx.json', function (data) {
            var output = "<div class='outer'>";
            for (var i in data.lbclassic1990) {
                output += "<div style='display:none;' class='lbclassic1990'id=" + "age" + data.lbclassic1990[i].ageinweeks + ">" + '<table class="table table-responsive"><tr class="cabecera"><th colspan="3"><center><strong>Age (weeks) ' + data.lbclassic1990[i].ageinweeks + '</strong></center></th></tr><tr><td>Egg No. per H.H.</td><td>cumul.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].cumul + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">Rate of Lay %</td><td>per H.H.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].perhh + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td>per H.D.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].perhd + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2"> Egg Weight (g)</td><td>egg weight in week</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggweightinweek + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td>egg mass cumul.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggmasscumul + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">Egg Mass -- g/H.D. -- kg/H.H.</td><td>egg mass in week</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggmassinweek + '</strong></td></tr><tr><td>egg mass cumul.</td><td><strong>' + data.lbclassic1990[i].eggmasscumul2 + '</strong></td></tr></table>' + "</div>";
            }
            output += "</div>";
            document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML = output;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much. That was the problem. I can't use load there, since the only page actually loaded is the index.html one, thanks again. edit: both solutions are correct but I'll give the correct answer to mario.kulmp beucase he was faster.